# CSS image not working

Tags: css, background-image

I am creating a website, and have tried many different ways to make a background image show up, but it is only ever visible in Visual Studio and not when I run the project.

Code:

```
Header
{
    background: url('file:///SomePath.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 176px;
    background-color: #AAAAFF;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: If the problem is that the image does not show up when the site is published on the web, it is because you are pointing to a local file. Unless the file exists in the same location on the web server, it will not be found.

Comment: You need to specify a path relative to the document root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the image in the same folder as the picture? Your best bet is to have them in the same folder to test them to make sure they work. I.E. put the picture and the CSS file in the same folder so your header will look like.

```
header {
background:url('CompetitiveStreakTopBanner.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
width: 100%; 
height: 176px; 
background-color: #AAAAFF; 
margin-top: 0px; 
background-size: contain;
}
```

If that works you can move the file to an other folder in the same containing folder and use something like `background:url('../Elements/CompetitiveStreakTopBanner.png');`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible culprits

1. You're using an absolute path to point to your image, which commonly leads to trouble when viewing your site from another location.

   If your image in the same folder as the file calling it, you can simply say `url(myImage.png)` without the rest of the path. Best practice is to point with relative paths, i.e. one relative to the root directory of the site, so `url(../images/myImage.png)`.
2. You are using the [shorthand method of writing CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) for the background by specifying `background` instead of `background-image` in your first line. 
   Shorthand CSS requires a certain set of properties in a certain order. If one of these is invalid/incorrect, the rest won't work as it will be interpreted as an invalid rule by browsers. `Background` can take:

   `background: color image repeat position`

   e.g. `background: black url(.../myImage.png) no-repeat top left;`

First try changing that, so: `background-image: url(myimage.png);`. Alternately, you can combine your CSS background properties into a single shorthand property:

```
width: 100%;
height: 176px;
margin-top: 0px;
background: #AAAAFF url('file:///SomePath.png') no-repeat top left;
background-size: contain;
```

If that doesn't work, try chaning the file path to relative as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

background: url('file:///SomePath.png');

with

background: url('http://www.yoursite/foldercontainingthepicture/picture.png');

Comment: remember to replace the text with proper names, of course :)

Comment: Ive uploaded the photo to dropbox, and put the link back in, the image now doesn't show in VS or when I run my application.

Header
{
    background: url('https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/CompetitiveStreakTemplate/CompetitiveStreakTopBanner.png?_subject_uid=9403629&w=AABITqEcPpNILKrkKE8BhW3QdtdkzWyiHrNy0KE-_H-8qA');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 176px;
    background-color: #AAAAFF;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-size: contain;
    }